# When can i use a normal distribution to describe my data?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, data-analysis

I have a dataset which is markedly left-skewed, and I wonder if it will be inappropriate to use the normal distribution curve to analyses the data given it's highly skewed?

Picture of my data:

[image: 1]

Comment: More importantly, you data seems to be **positive**. Normal distribution is *almost never* suited for such cases.

Comment: Do you why that is? :)

Comment: What? Why your data is positive? Or why the normal distribution is not suited for positive data? I think both are pretty clear...

Comment: How exactly do you want to analyze your data?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the underlying data? Is it continuous or discrete? Bounded from below/above? It's not clear from the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data seems to be non-negative. The normal distribution is *almost never* well suited for such case. You might want to try a [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution), possibly just an [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).

Moreover, you should consider if your data is continuous or discrete. In the latter case, you might prefer [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) or [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

If your data is also bounded from above, then [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) and [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) are an option.

Comment: It could be lognormal too.